# PHP header() sends me to webside.com/folder/webside.com/folder/index.php but should send me to webside.com/folder/index.php

Tags: php, header

so I build a logout button for my little project and it sends the user to logout.php where this code is locatetet:
(user clicks on button in webside.com/folder/smth.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['hasAccess'] = 0;
header('Location: ../../webside.com/folder/index.php', true, 301);
exit;
```

and it should send me to webside.com/folder/index.php but it sends me to:
webside.com/folder/webside.com/folder/index.php

So I tried:

- without ../../
- just /folder/index.php
- just index.php
- just ./
  but its always the same.

Comment: I think you're looking for: `//webside.com/folder/index.php`. See: [What is a URL?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

Comment: KIKO Software I tried it but it is still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

So I accedently used the wrong response code in my code (302) the rigth one is as in the example 301 so this code works just fine when you change it so in front of the url is a // as @KIKO Software said in a comment.